# Success Audit spamming event log

Tags: 2007, authentication, logging, auditing

I have set up a standard MOSS installation using forms authentication with NTLM.

I have noticed that there are a lot of audit success events in the windows event log is this normal? It makes it very difficult to try and trouble shoot anything as the event log is full.

Thanks,

Dirk

Comment: I would like to see if we can suppress auditing for a specific user. Not filtering after loging. I want to prevent auditing to the logs..

Answer (score 1):

You can either **disable success audits entirely** ([Tired of all those "Success Audit" event entries?](http://msmvps.com/blogs/kwsupport/archive/2006/08/16/107860.aspx)) or **use the Filter function of Event Viewer** when you are checking the logs.

Comment: So there is no way to stop it logging in as much?

Comment: @Dirk I don't understand what you mean by *no way to stop it logging in as much* - it is possible **not to log** successful logins and the article describes how to do it.

Comment: I have never seen so many entries in the event log. It is actually stopping getting any information about a different issue I am having with the site.

Comment: @Dirk I don't understand the problem - did you try to disable success event logging or use the *Filter* function to hide success event?

Comment: @Dirk What OS does your SharePoint machine use? What exactly is this different issues?